# R: installing package to a different location from R base

Tags: r, install.packages

I am accessing R-3.4 from a location on a shared drive. IT have configured it such that, when I install a package, it will default to installing it on my local drive. In many cases, it succeeds with a warning, but a few packages are failing, saying they can't access other libraries/packages.

The location on the shared drive is available in `.libpaths()`, and when I specifically install to this location using `install.packages("package_name", lib = .libpaths()[2])`, these packages install successfully.

Unfortunately, IT have told me I'm not allowed to install to the shared drive. So: is there a way that I can install a package to my local drive, but tell `install.packages()` to refer to the shared drive for any dependencies?

(This problem has so far arisen with installing `arules`, `RGoogleAnalytics`, and `googleAnalyticsR`, but I suspect they won't be the only ones.)

Comment: It sounds like your local drive is _not_ the first entry in your `.libPaths()`?  Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should have been clearer: the first entry in `.libpaths()` is a location on my local drive; the second entry is the one on the shared drive (where the R base is also installed).

Comment: Oh, so when IT says you're "not allowed" to install into the shared drive, they are putting the onus on you not to do it instead of restricting your write access to the folder.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but you can try `install.package("package_name", dependencies = FALSE)`

Comment: why dont you install everything including a clean new version of R and all the libraries that you ever wanted on your local machine? In the installation steps, as long as you dont write the version to registry, you do not require admin rights. Hopefully, you are still allowed to download the R binaries to install in the first place though...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that option open to me! Whilst IT have only *told me* not to install new packages to the shared drive, they've got all other aspects on a very strict lockdown, so I can't install any new software myself, even to my local drive.